# How can server/borwser persist the hash value while redirecting

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat, nginx

I have a same base code deployed locally using tomcat and on production using nginx. The issue is on click of logout button the production server is persisting the hash value but on local its not. For example a link

```
<a href="/auth/logout">Logout</a>
```

when I am on url http://myapp.com/home/#/Specific and click logout here is whats happening.
On Production its redirecting to

```
http://myapp.com/auth/logout#/Specific
```

and on Local its

```
http://localhost:8080/auth/logout
```

what could be the possible issue? Is it nginx handling it automatically?

Comment: the server doesn't see the fragment part of the URL, you will have to use javascript in the browser.

Comment: What do you mean by "redirecting" you don't get a 302 or something, right?

Comment: @Jasen Yes server does't see but how it upading the url with hashvalue on production and not on local

Comment: @JensSchauder No 302, it simple click on a link

Comment: @coure2011 there must be something client-side doing it

Comment: So, the link looks the same in the HTML source in your browser? If so, what kind of javascript stuff do you have on that page?